# What is a "relationship talk"?

Tags: meaning, idioms, phrases

Many dating advices include the phrase "relationship talks". In my understanding, before a relationship, a relation talk is a talk about the plans on relationship; during a relationship, a relationship talk is a talk about the relationship itself, like how does it go.

Is my understanding correct? Does the phrase "relationship talks" have specific meanings? In general sense, does it usually refer to the talk before relationship or after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is almost entirely context dependent.

It just means "a talk about the relationship, or relationships in general".

I would understand it (without any further context) to be a talk that a young person has with their parent about relationships (and consent, and sex and so on).

Comment: I agree it is context dependent. For the context it is about the talk between a young woman and man. I think it still means "a talk about the relationship, or relationships in general"?